# How can I get Star Trek : Armada to run under Windows 7

Tags: star-trek-armada

I installed Star Trek : Armada on my Win 7 - 32Bit laptop, and it worked with out complaint; however, when I try to run it, it complains that I'm out of memory.

My laptop has way more than the minimum requirements. What gives? Is it possible to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found [here](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f59/old-game-star-trek-armada-i-problems-with-windows-7-a-412303.html#post3066883):

Checklist:

1. Install armada on windows 7
2. Patch to 1.2
3. go to armada Dir C:/program files/activistion/star trek - armada
4. right click on armada.exe - properties (here comes the fun part)
5. go to compatibility tab
6. set it for windows xp sp2
7. run in 256 colors

   1. set to run as administrator
8. Check armada CD is in the drive and go have fun

For online play, won servers are no longer supported. So we use Game ranger which is a free small program which is able to host armada as well as other games. I'll walk you threw online.

1. Downlad Game Ranger - http://www.gameranger.com - install, register.
2. connect and you will shown a list of games
3. click on the top bar community